# Granting access to root from localhost

Tags: shell, ubuntu, vagrant

I'm following this [link](http://www.thisprogrammingthing.com/2013/getting-started-with-vagrant/) on how to set up a LAMP stack with Vagrant.

Because that link uses wordpress, I had to modify the code a bit. However I'm getting an error:

`access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

This error occurs when I'm trying to create user, create database, etc in my shell file.. I've searched this error online and it suggests that I need to grant access to root from localhost. I'm not sure how to do this in my `provisions.sh`. Can anyone provide some advice?

Here is my shell file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#set variable
ROOTPASS=default_root_pw

# setting answers to questions during install
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server/root_password password $ROOTPASS'
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server/root_password_again password $ROOTPASS'

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install mysql-server-5.5 php5-mysql apache2 php5

# check if databasesetup file exists, if it doesn't, it means this is first time 
# and we should create user"

if [ ! -f /var/log/databasesetup ];
then
    echo "CREATE USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'user_password'" | mysql -uroot -p$ROOTPASS
    echo "CREATE DATABASE my_database" | mysql -uroot -p$ROOTPASS
    echo "GRANT ALL ON my_database.* TO 'user'@'localhost'" | mysql -uroot -p$ROOTPASS
    echo "flush privileges" | mysql -uroot -p$ROOTPASS

    # create databasesetup file to prevent recreating users in future ..."
    touch /var/log/databasesetup

    # checking if initial.sql exists to restore it into VM database...

    if [ -f /vagrant/data/initial.sql ];
    then
        mysql -uroot -p$ROOTPASS my_database < /vagrant/data/initial.sql
    fi
fi

if [ ! -h /var/www ]; 
then 
    rm -rf /var/www sudo
    ln -s /vagrant/public /var/www

    service apache2 restart
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a quoting error.  Within single quotes, `$ROOTPASS` is just a static string.  You want double quotes in the `debconf-set-selections` snippet.

I would switch to a here document to avoid the code duplication, anyway.

```
sudo debconf-set-selections <<-____HERE
    mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server/root_password password $ROOTPASS
    mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server/root_password_again password $ROOTPASS
____HERE
```

(Coincidentally, this also reduces the line width so that you could actually see the error.  There is a reason decent editors scream at you when your lines grow too long.)